# How can I configure load balanceing multiple SharePoint2010 web server using Network Load Balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, deployment

How can I configure load balanceing multiple SharePoint2010 web server using Network Load Balancing ?

I googoled and binged , not much resources could be found on SharePoint2010.Can anyone point me to some useful resouces?I am pretty new to the IT Pro side of SharePoint , any general guidelines would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Fabian's article here for reference when I have to do this kinda stuff:

http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/setting-up-nlb-for-your-wfes-in-sharepoint/

It has things that I always miss when setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used [this guide](http://www.combined-knowledge.com/Downloads/2007/How%20to%20scale%20out%20a%20SharePoint%20farm%20and%20configure%20IIS%207%20Microsoft%20Network%20Load%20Balancing%20on%20windows%20server%202008.pdf) published by Combined-Knowledge, written by Steve Smith.